# Tying mousemove to style attribute in Angular app produces ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Tags: angular

In my Angular app I have a component, which is positioned dynamically using `top` and `left` CSS attributes and follows the mouse position  (like a Google Trends graph tooltip).

The `getTop()` and `getLeft()` methods depend on an `@Input` variable, which stores current mouse position as a property. Those properties change on `mousemove` in parent component, after which the CSS attributes are recalculated and the component is repositioned.

Template:

```
<app-tooltip
  [style.top]="getTop()"
  [style.left]="getLeft()"
>
</app-tooltip>
```

TS:

```
...
@Input() tooltip: Tooltip;

getTop(): string {
  return `${this.tooltip.mouseY}px`;
}

getLeft(): string {
  return `${this.tooltip.mouseX}px`;
}
...
```

Tooltip.ts

```
export class Tooltip {
  ...
  mouseX: number;  // changed externally on (mousemove)
  mouseY: number;  // changed externally on (mousemove)
  ...
}
```

**The problem**: moving the mouse around produces an `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError`, stating that `left` and `top` CSS attributes have changed during the double change detection cycle (since I am running in dev mode).

Interestingly, if I move the mouse slowly enough, no errors are produced (possibly both change detection cycles happen before next `mousemove` is emitted?).

How can i fix this error and clear my console of hundreds of these errors?

*I am aware what `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` means. I am certain the change detection itself is not causing the styles to get updated, and pretty sure the reason is behind the rate of `mousemove` firing events.*

Comment: and how do you update the @Input() tooltip thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because angular Change detection triggers all of the components tree, it is pretty bad thing to subscribe to events that are "spamming" ones, such as mousemove and scroll

instead this is a good usecase to apply styles programmaticaly, instead of through model.

```
@ViewChild(TooltipComponent, {read: ElementRef}) tooltipRef: ElementRef;
constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, private ngZone: NgZone){}

ngOnInit(){
  this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {

     this.moveZone.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
        this.renderer.setStyle(this.tooltipRef.nativeElement, 'left', e.left)
        this.renderer.setStyle(this.tooltipRef.nativeElement, 'top', e.top)
     })

  })
}
```